# censoring tic with TikZ package

Tags: pgfplots

I've managed to create a plot for a censored Gamma pdf. I'm now trying to change the color of the censoring line to cyan (now it is gray). I've managed to change the color of the distribution's contour and of the xtick, but not of the remaining censoring line. 
I was wondering if anyone had any suggestion for me to try. Many thanks!

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);}
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:7.0, samples=100,
  axis lines=left, xlabel=$n_t^i$, ylabel=$f_n(.)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=east},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=north},
  height=5.5cm, width=9.5cm,
  xtick={6.5}, 
  xtick style={color=cyan},
  ytick=\empty, 
  xticklabels={$\bar n (\theta_t)$},
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major,
  xmax=10
  ]
\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!cyan,domain=0:6.5] {gammapdf(x,9,0.5)};
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=0:6.5] {gammapdf(x,9,0.5)} \closedcycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the grid style (here say x axis) via adding

```
major x grid style={draw=cyan!20},
```

to the axis options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works. However, how would you do it if you had 2 censoring points and you wanted to use two different colors? Say red and cyan. Thanks again.

Comment: @Colenso For two of them you can use extra x ticks. But if more than two then draw the lines using `\draw ...` expressions by yourself.